# SQL statement inside swift

Tags: sql, swift

Not sure if this is the right place, but as Stackoverflow is my go to place, I will start here.

I have a swift app that has a main menu that lists several "groups" of marines species, i.e. Fish, Sharks, Corals.  After selecting a "group" item on the menu, this triggers to a subGroup menu that will list subgroup items, like Soft Corals, Hard Corals and so on.  The system works most fine, however there are a few subgroups (out of 196) that when selected crash the app with an beyond bounds error.

I have checked the database many times now as I know which subGroups cause the crash.  I cannot find anything odd there.

So, that leaves code or SQL

My app quite large, so posting code would not be practical.

I think the issue might be in my SQL file where the wrong data might be called up and I came across this line.  Can someone please give me a laymen term of what is happening here?  I question the "RL_SubTypes_for_Groups" statement.

```
static let SelectSubCategoriesNamesForGroupName  = "SELECT RL_Subgroups.name FROM RL_Subgroups INNER JOIN RL_SubTypes_for_Groups ON RL_Subgroups.rl_groups_id = RL_SubTypes_for_Groups.id WHERE RL_SubTypes_for_Groups.name = \"%@\" ORDER BY UPPER(RL_Subgroups.name) ASC"
```

Can some say if there is something jumping out here that seems wrong?

Comment: use breakpoints to find the crashing code. if the sql is bad you will not get a crash, but an error from the sql process.

Comment: Thanks, John.  I am further testing and it seems that some of the subMenu items have commas in it, example "Goby, Shrimp". I am testing now to see if commas are the culprit, which I think they are.

Comment: Just so you know, "," cannot be used for a sqlite menu item, but "(" and "-" can